# How can I change SpinnerNumberModel based on the value of another JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, max, toolbar, jspinner

I'm trying to do a toolBar in my form that contains some `JSpinner` that changes the width and height of a rectangle.

In this toolBar I've another `JSpinner` with a **maximum value that's based on the current value** of the width and height `JSpinners`.

I've tried to modify the `SpinnerNumberModel` of the `JSpinner` in the `stateChanged()` event, but this solution not works..

There's someone knows how to do it?

**Creation of width and height `JSpinners`:**

```
        //Creo il modello per i JSpinners
        widthModel = new SpinnerNumberModel((double)STD_DIMENSION, 1, 999, 1);
        heightModel = new SpinnerNumberModel((double)STD_DIMENSION, 1, 999, 1);
        //Creo pannello per widthSpinner
        widthSpinner = new JSpinner(widthModel);
        widthSpinner.addChangeListener(this);
        widthPanel = new JPanel();
        widthPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        widthPanel.add(new JLabel("Larghezza: "));
        widthPanel.add(widthSpinner);
        //Creo pannello per heightSpinner
        heightSpinner = new JSpinner(heightModel);
        heightSpinner.addChangeListener(this);
        heightPanel = new JPanel();
        heightPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        heightPanel.add(new JLabel("Altezza: "));
        heightPanel.add(heightSpinner);
```

**Creation of the other `JSpinner` based on the value of the precedent:**

```
        //Creo lightModel e sunSpinner
        lightModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(canvas.getLightMax()/2, 0, canvas.getLightMax(), 1);
        sunSpinner = new JSpinner(lightModel);
        sunSpinner.setEnabled(false);
        sunSpinner.addChangeListener(this);
```

**`stateChanged()` event:**

```
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(widthSpinner)) {
            canvas.setRealWidth((double)widthSpinner.getValue());

            lightModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(canvas.getLightMax()/2, 0, canvas.getLightMax(), 1);
            sunSpinner.setModel(lightModel);
        }

        if (e.getSource().equals(heightSpinner)) {
            canvas.setRealHeight((double)heightSpinner.getValue());

            lightModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(canvas.getLightMax()/2, 0, canvas.getLightMax(), 1);
            sunSpinner.setModel(lightModel);
        }
    }
```

**`getLightMax()` is a method that returns a dimension based on the activation of some `JRadioButtons`:**

```
    public double getLightMax() {
        if (horizontalBool) {
            return realHeight;
        } else {
            return realWidth;
        }
    }
```

I hope I posted all necessary codes, if not just ask.

**SOLVED:**

I had forgotten to initialize the `horizontalBool` variable and also I didn't called the model change in the `actionPerformed()` event when you press on one of the `JRadioButtons`.

Thanks to all.

Comment: `"I hope I posted all necessary codes, if not just ask."` -- Please create and post your [mcve] so we can play with a small compilable and runnable program and so that we can test your code ourselves, and hopefully modify it so that it will work. Note that we **do not want to see your entire program**, nor should you post a link to a code repository. Instead keep it small, keep it simple, and make it functioning. Luck.

Comment: maybe canvas.getLightMax() always return the same value

Comment: I did my simple and runnable toolBar example as I was advised. I had forgotten to initialize the `horizontalBool` variable and also I didn't called the model change in the `actionPerformed()` event when you press on one of the `JRadioButtons`. I apologize for the useless question.